# Why does printf only print the first word in a string?

Tags: c, input, stream, printf, fgets

I'm fairly new to C programming, so I was playing around with reading data from a file using fgets() and sscanf(). I set up a real simple experiment here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    char szInputBuffer[100];
    FILE *pFile;
    char szInput[100];
    int i;

    pFile = fopen("MyFile.txt", "r");
    printf("This is the input: \n\n");

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; ++i)
    {
        fgets(szInputBuffer, 100, pFile);
        sscanf(szInputBuffer, "%s", szInput);
        printf("%s", szInput);
    }
}
```

I am reading from MyFile.txt which contains simply:

```
This is more input.
The next line of Input.
More input here.
```

How ever my output is:

```
This is the input:
ThisTheMore
```

Which is the first word from every line. I found that when I add a second %s to the printf statement like so:

```
printf("%s%s", szInput);
```

That I achieve the desired output:

```
This is the input:
This is more input.
The next line of Input.
More input here.
```

Can someone please explain this to me? I have never heard of using a second placeholder to get the entire string. I have not been able to find anything that helps with my issue here. I have seen example programs in class that only use one %s in the print statement and the entire string is printed. Thanks for helping out a curious programmer!

P.S I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, using the Geany IDE. I know some of you guys ask about that.

Comment: The `%s` specifier for `sscanf` means to read the first word. If you want to print the whole line then just skip that step

Comment: giving more format specifiers than subsequent arguments to `printf` causes undefined behaviour; you can't really read anything into what happens after that

Comment: According to my knowledge, your use of sscanf is unnecessary. The fgets call will retrieve the text from the file. I would ditch the sscanf and print out the szInputBuffer instead.

Comment: That much I know, but can you explain why doing %s%s in the printf statement also works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sscanf(szInputBuffer, "%s", szInput);
```

The format specifier `%s` fetches the string until a space or newline character is encountered so you are just getting a single word in order to get the whole line just nul terminate the string after `fgets()` as `fgets()` comes with a newline character and print out the string.

The scanf() man says `%s`

> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer
>   must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the
>   input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added
>   automatically. The input string stops at white space or at the maximum
>   field width, whichever occurs first.

Do

```
size_t n;
fgets(szInputBuffer, 100, pFile);
n = strlen(szInputBuffer);
if(n>0 && szInputBuffer[n-1] == '\n')
 szInputBuffer[n-1] = '\0';
 printf("%s\n",szInputBuffer);
```

If you are looking to break the line into strings and print out each word in a line then go for `strtok()` with space as delimiter.

---

If you see

```
printf("%s%s", szInput);
```

working then what you have is undefined behavior.printf() says that the number of format specifiers should match number of values which needs to be printed out . Note that even with type mismatch the behavior is undefined .

Comment: I know that much about %s, However what I don't understand is why using %s%s generates the proper output. Is that a thing in C? Could you shed some light?

Comment: @AlejandroZapien I don't get what you mean by `%s %s` then there has to be 2 variables to which you scan your value basically `%s` is doing what it does so since there is a space it stops scanning

Comment: If I do printf("%s%s", szInput); It some how generates the exact input I want. I encourage you to copy the code, run it, then modify the printf to have "%s%s" and run it again. For whatever reason it works. Why is that?

Comment: Hmm... Okay thank you, I can see now based on your response and the rest of the (amazing!) SOF community the reasoning and logic behind this concept. Thanks guys!